# Data Frame into bins

Tags: python, pandas

From the data frame, I am trying to use the 'mean' column to separate the values into 3 bins.

```
                     num_countries         mean
0         'Europe',             25   161.572326
1           'Asia',              7   607.983830
2  'North America',              3  1560.438095
3  'South America',              2   199.148901
4      'Australia',              1   218.021429
5          'Africa'              1   213.846154
6        'Oceania',              1    39.378571
```

my bins are

```
bins = [-np.inf, (in_order['mean'].mean()-in_order['mean'].std()), (in_order['mean'].mean()+in_order['mean'].std()), np.inf]
```

which results to [-inf, -100.38831237389581, 957.64239998696303, inf]

Then when I try to put them into the bins, this is what happens.

```
binned = pd.cut(in_order.mean, bins)

TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-229-3343eeaf99d6> in <module>()
----> 1 binned = pd.cut(in_order.mean, bins)

C:\Users\zkrumlinde\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\tile.pyc in cut(x, bins, right, labels, retbins, precision, include_lowest)
    117     return _bins_to_cuts(x, bins, right=right, labels=labels,
    118                          retbins=retbins, precision=precision,
--> 119                          include_lowest=include_lowest)
    120 
    121 
C:\Users\zkrumlinde\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\tile.pyc in _bins_to_cuts(x, bins, right, labels, retbins, precision, name, include_lowest)
    222 
    223         levels = np.asarray(levels, dtype=object)
--> 224         np.putmask(ids, na_mask, 0)
    225         fac = Categorical(ids - 1, levels, ordered=True, fastpath=True)
    226     else:
TypeError: putmask() argument 1 must be numpy.ndarray, not numpy.int32
```

Comment: I'd recommend binning into quantiles. Use `pd.qcut`.

Comment: One other issue here is that `in_order.mean` may confuse the pandas method `mean` with the name of your `mean` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with your data:

```
print(df)
       continent  num_countries         mean
0         Europe             25   161.572326
1           Asia              7   607.983830
2  North America              3  1560.438095
3  South America              2   199.148901
4      Australia              1   218.021429
5         Africa              1   213.846154
6        Oceania              1    39.378571
```

I believe the main problem is the manner in which you reference the `mean` column. Do note that `mean` is also a first order function on a `pd.DataFrame` object. Observe:

```
print(df.mean)
<bound method DataFrame.mean of ....>
```

If you want to access the `mean` column (and not the `mean` function), you'll need to do so with `df['mean']`.

```
s = pd.cut(in_order['mean'], bins)
print(s)
0    (-100.388, 957.642]
1    (-100.388, 957.642]
2         (957.642, inf]
3    (-100.388, 957.642]
4    (-100.388, 957.642]
5    (-100.388, 957.642]
6    (-100.388, 957.642]
Name: mean, dtype: category
Categories (3, interval[float64]): [(-inf, -100.388] < (-100.388, 957.642] < (957.642, inf]]

print(s.cat.codes)
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    1
dtype: int8
```

---

Alternatively, have you considered `pd.qcut`? You can quite simply pass the number of bins and your data will be binned into that many quantiles.

```
s = pd.qcut(df['mean'], 4)
print(s)
0      (39.378, 180.361]
1    (413.003, 1560.438]
2    (413.003, 1560.438]
3     (180.361, 213.846]
4     (213.846, 413.003]
5     (180.361, 213.846]
6      (39.378, 180.361]
Name: mean, dtype: category
Categories (4, interval[float64]): [(39.378, 180.361] < (180.361, 213.846] < (213.846, 413.003] <
                                    (413.003, 1560.438]]

print(s.cat.codes)
0    0
1    3
2    3
3    1
4    2
5    1
6    0
dtype: int8
```

Your method above bins most of your data to a single category, so I believe this should work better for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `np.searchsorted`

```
x = in_order['mean'].values
sig = x.std()
mu = x.mean()

in_order.assign(bins=np.searchsorted([mu - sig, mu + sig], x))

       continent  num_countries         mean  bins
0         Europe             25   161.572326     1
1           Asia              7   607.983830     1
2  North America              3  1560.438095     2
3  South America              2   199.148901     1
4      Australia              1   218.021429     1
5         Africa              1   213.846154     1
6        Oceania              1    39.378571     1
```

---

We can do that with labels if you'd like

```
x = in_order['mean'].values
sig = x.std()
mu = x.mean()

labels = np.array(['< μ - σ', 'μ ± σ', '> μ + σ'])

in_order.assign(bins=labels[np.searchsorted([mu - sig, mu + sig], x)])
       continent  num_countries         mean     bins
0         Europe             25   161.572326    μ ± σ
1           Asia              7   607.983830    μ ± σ
2  North America              3  1560.438095  > μ + σ
3  South America              2   199.148901    μ ± σ
4      Australia              1   218.021429    μ ± σ
5         Africa              1   213.846154    μ ± σ
6        Oceania              1    39.378571    μ ± σ
```